# cql_filter with strToUpperCase() fails with "Cannot do natural order without a primary key"

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, wfs, cql-filter

I'm trying to convert a query into uppercase in a GeoServer WFS request. According to the [Filter Function](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html) reference this can be achieved using `strToUpperCase()`.

This is working successfully on a [sample GeoServer site](http://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/web/) where both of these queries return the expected result `"STATE_NAME": "Illinois"`

- [CQL_FILTER=STATE_NAME='Illinois'](http://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/topp/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=topp:states&CQL_FILTER=STATE_NAME=%27Illinois%27)
- [CQL_FILTER=strToUpperCase(STATE_NAME)='ILLINOIS'](http://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/topp/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=topp:states&CQL_FILTER=strToUpperCase(STATE_NAME)=%27ILLINOIS%27)

However, on my own GeoServer (version 2.10.2), an equivalent `cql_filter` (against a text field) works correctly without `strToUpperCase`:

http://apollo:8080/geoserver/loceng/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=loceng:rv_claims_lodgement_geo&CQL_FILTER=locality%3D%27Rozelle%27

... but fails with the following error when I include the `strToUpperCase` filter function:

http://apollo:8080/geoserver/loceng/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=loceng:rv_claims_lodgement_geo&CQL_FILTER=strToUpperCase(locality)%3D%27ROZELLE%27

```
<ServiceException>
   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException java.io.IOException
   Cannot do natural order without a primary key, please add it or
   specify a manual sort over existing attributes
</ServiceException>
```

The layer's data source is a PostgreSQL table with the field defined as `character varying`, and there is an ascending index on that field.

Other layers in my local GeoServer, which are sourced from the same PostgreSQL instance, do not exhibit this error when I use `strToUpperCase` so the problem appears to be isolated to this layer/PostgreSQL table.

How can I debug this problem and allow the use of `strToUpperCase` on this dataset?

Comment: can you add the exact URLs you are requesting (use localhost and topp:states) - it looks like you have triggered a sort on the second request. Also does your table have a primary key?

Comment: In addition to Ian's good suggestion, that demo server is also a 2.10.x, in particular, the nightly build of the day... did you try upgrading to the latest 2.10.x release? Also, try attaching the full stack trace to the report (you'll find it in geoserver.log)

Comment: @iant thanks for the tips, which set me on the right track. See my answer below for the resolution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out there were two problems:

- firstly I needed to add the Primary Key, as mentioned in the GeoServer error message
- the second problem was with the `character varying` field definition in PostgreSQL. I changed this to `text` and GeoServer's `strToUpperCase()` now works correctly.

Comment: As an aside, I found that `strToUpperCase()` introduced a noticeable performance penalty, so I decided to pre-calculate a new field in the PostgreSQL table which was the uppercase value of my desired field and simply search this directly. Searching against this field was much faster

Answer (score 1):

Why would you even use strToUpperCase there, if you just need case insensitive comparison, would it be easier to use `strEqualsIgnoreCase` from [the docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html) you linked

```
strEqualsIgnoreCase a:String, b:String  Returns true if the two strings are equal ignoring case considerations
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I missed that function. `strEqualsIgnoreCase`. For simplicity, let's just say I want to get `strToUpperCase` working and leave out the case-insensitivity